# Extracting streaming video from swf

Tags: video, streaming, video-streaming

I am trying to speed up this video by 1.25x to 1.5x, udacity style.

I tried grabbing the http://smart.if.uidaho.edu/courses/f2012/cs512/ using the Download Flash & Video Firefox plugin, but it only grabbed the swf player that streams the video.

Is there any other way to download this video? (as well as future videos).

As a final solution, I can use video capture software while I'm not using the computer, but I don't want that hassle and time delay if possible.

Comment: There are tons of tools, browser addons available out there..try some other addon for FF or Chrome...I use IDM....but it is a paid software..

Comment: Would you mind checking if IDM can grab this video?

The problem is that I can grab the media player, but not what the media player is streaming. Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HiDownload was able to grab the flv file. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [VideoCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/video_cache_view.html). (its free and lightweight)
If the video file is stored in your browser's cache, this utility can help you to extract the video file from the cache and save it for watching it in the future.

Comment: Nope didn't work. I'm going to try Orbit and HiDownload as well